# How to Create Identity Provider using ARM template for azure function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

How to Create azure identity provider in azure portal using ARM template for the azure functions.

ARM template to deploy the azure resources. I am able to create the azure functions but I also need to create the Authentication -> Identity provider (Microsoft) on the fly .

Comment: This question isn't very clear. What's the goal? Do you mean you're trying to configure your Azure Function with a Managed Identity?

Comment: I am preparing the ARM template to deploy the azure resources. I am able to create the azure functions but I also need to create the  Authentication -> Identity provider (microsoft) on the fly .

Comment: Hello @user2020832 , Any update on this .!!. Does the provided answer resolved your issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have tried in our environment to create an Azure function with azure AD Authentication and Identity provider(Microsoft) with below template:

***Prerequisites***:-

- Register an Application in Azure AD(`AZURE AD>APP REGISTRATION`).
- Enable ID tokens (used for implicit and hybrid flows) .

***ARM TEMPLATE***:-

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "siteName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[concat('FuncApp-', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of your Web Site."
            }
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "[concat('store', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "clientId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "ClientId of the APP registration to be used by the Function APP authentication"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "hostingPlanName": "[concat('hpn-', resourceGroup().name)]",
        "storageAccountid": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
            "kind": "functionapp,linux",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
                "adminEnabled": true,
                "enabledHostNames": [
                    "[concat(parameters('siteName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
                    "[concat(parameters('siteName'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]"
                ],
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "ipBasedSslState": "NotConfigured",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'),'.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "ipBasedSslState": "NotConfigured",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                    ],
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
                            "value": "python"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
                            "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
            "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "linux",
            "properties": {
                "reserved": true
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "Standard",
                "Name": "S1"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            }
        },
        {
                "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'), '/authsettingsV2')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
                "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
                "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                "properties": {
                    "platform": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "runtimeVersion": "~1"
                    },
                    "globalValidation": {
                    "requireAuthentication": true,
                    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
                    "redirectToProvider": "azureactivedirectory"
                    },
                    "identityProviders": {
                    "azureActiveDirectory": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {
                        "openIdIssuer": "[concat('https://sts.windows.net/',tenant().tenantId,'/v2.0')]",
                        "clientId": "[parameters('clientId')]",
                        "clientSecretSettingName": "MICROSOFT_PROVIDER_AUTHENTICATION_SECRET"
                        },
                        "login": {
                        "disableWWWAuthenticate": false
                        },
                        "validation": {
                        "jwtClaimChecks": {},
                        "allowedAudiences": [],
                        "defaultAuthorizationPolicy": {
                            "allowedPrincipals": {}
                        }
                        }
                    },
                    "facebook": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {},
                        "login": {}
                    },
                    "gitHub": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {},
                        "login": {}
                    },
                    "google": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {},
                        "login": {},
                        "validation": {}
                    },
                    "twitter": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {}
                    },
                    "legacyMicrosoftAccount": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {},
                        "login": {},
                        "validation": {}
                    },
                    "apple": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "registration": {},
                        "login": {}
                    }
                    },
                    "login": {
                    "routes": {},
                    "tokenStore": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "tokenRefreshExtensionHours": 72,
                        "fileSystem": {},
                        "azureBlobStorage": {}
                    },
                    "preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins": false,
                    "cookieExpiration": {
                        "convention": "FixedTime",
                        "timeToExpiration": "08:00:00"
                    },
                    "nonce": {
                        "validateNonce": true,
                        "nonceExpirationInterval": "00:05:00"
                    }
                    },
                    "httpSettings": {
                    "requireHttps": true,
                    "routes": {
                        "apiPrefix": "/.auth"
                    },
                    "forwardProxy": {
                        "convention": "NoProxy"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE: *In client id provide the app registration application id which you have created earlier***

***OUTPUT:-***
Deployed using:

```
az deployment group create -n TestDeployment -g <resourcegroupname> --template-file "C:\Path\to\template.json"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

***NOTE:-*** In APP Registration we have to add reply uri by using [***`azure cli cmd`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-update) with  `https://yourfunctionappname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback`

```
az ad app update --id <objectid> --reply-urls https://funcapp-xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

[image]
[image]

***Tested Function app output:***
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer - this is the first example of authorization config I've seen that actually works! You don't need to define all the identity providers by the way, if you only have one, you can define only it.